# Find Files Which Are Modified and Transfer to another server

Tags: php, linux

I need to find files which were modified yesterday, and then transfer those files to another server. I know how to find files and copy to another directory within the same server.

I also know how to copy file from one server to another:

```
scp -r  username@hostname:sourcedirectory username@hostname:destinationdirectory
```

But I do not know how to find files which are modified on a particular day and then transfer them to another server. And also I don't want to create a directory to keep those modified files in the source server.

I don't know much Linux. So if anything seems stupid, please pardon me.

Comment: How are you finding files modified yesterday? If you're using `find`, you could always modify your process to use the `-exec` argument to launch `scp`, How are you defining "yesterday", anyway? Do you mean during the previous calendar day, or the previous 24 hours?

Comment: Hi, Kevin i solved this part of my problem.It was pretty naive from me.Yes you are right we can use -exec and I did it that way.The command is:-  find srcdirectory -maxdepth 1 -mtime -1 -exec scp -r "{}" username@hostname:destdirectory \;

Comment: But Now, there is a new problem related to it.I write my command in a php file and scheduled a cron job in cpanel,But it is throwing a strange error.My code in php file:-       <?php
echo php -v; 
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn ssh username@hostname 
expect "password:"
send "mypassword"
interact
find srcdirectory -maxdepth 1 -mtime -1 -exec scp -r "{}" username@hostname:destdirectory \;
?>                The Error it showing me is:-    PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'ssh' (T_STRING) in /home/usr/public_html/demo.php on line 4.     Can you tell me what is going wrong here.Thanks

Comment: Sorry -- I think you'll need to enlist somebody who knows more about PHP.

Comment: Thanks anyway Kevin